# Python cache overwrite if script loaded twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, modularity

I load my python script from the Linux terminal like `python3 script.py`. I noticed that python will create a `__pycache__` named folder where it will store some sort of cache, especially if I use imported modules from other files, which I do.

I don't know how exactly the caching works so I am asking this question just to be sure.

My question is that if I load the same `python3 script.py` file from 2 differently opened terminals, will the second program run overwrite the cache of the first one thereby sabotaging the calculation of it?

My script file contains a calculation with random initialization, so every time `script.py` is loaded it gives a different output, so it would make sense to run multiple instances at the same time, that is why I run it 2 times from different terminals, but it seems like they share the same `__pycache__` folder and the same modules imported inside them.

Will this method overwrite and sabotage the calculation, or will the 2 instances run in parralel without interfering with one another?

Comment: That's not what the pycache directory is. It's just a container for bytecode files, ie *.pyc. It doesn't have anything to do with runtime data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so if hypothetically saying, the pycache folder were to be overwritten while the script is running, it would not corrupt the script inside the memory right?

Comment: No there is no relation. The bytecode file is loaded on startup (or first module import) and then not referenced again.